# Extension of a family of vectors to a basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space. $\dim V=n$

Let $v_1,...,v_k \in V$ linearly independent.

Let $E$ be a generating set of vectors of $V$

Show that there exist $v_{k+1},...,v_n \in E$ st. $v_1,...,v_n$ are a basis of $V$.

My thoughts:

$v_1,...,v_k$ can be extended to a basis of V by vectors $v'_{k+1},...,v'_n$. Now the $v'$s can be expressed by E, but I will have to show, that the vectors of E needed will be lin. ind. to $v_1,...,v_k$ as well.

Comment: See [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712995/basis-on-vector-space-v/713113#713113). Note that $V$ doesn't have to be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Show that if one of the vectors you add is a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_k$, then you still obtain a generating set of $V$ if you just don't add that vector.