# Basis on vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $S_i$ is a set of linearly independent vectors of vector space $V$ and $S_g$ a set of generators of $V$. Prove that it exist $S'_g\subset S_g$ that $S_i\cup S'_g$ is a basis of $V$.

Notice that $V$ is not necessarily finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about finitely-dimensional spaces, this is exactly [Steinitz exchange lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma).

If you are interested in infinitely-dimensional space, I think that you only need to modify a little the standard proof of existence of [Hamel basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamel_basis) based on [Zorn Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn_lemma). This proof can be found [in many places](http://www.google.com/search?q=hamel+zorn). (Or maybe I should say that it is more similar to the proof of the fact, that every linearly independent subset of $V$ is contained in a Hamel basis of $V$.)

We will work with the system
$$\mathcal P=\{S\subseteq S_g; S\cup S_i\text{ is linearly independent}\}.$$
We check that for any chain $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal P$ we also have $\bigcup\mathcal C\in\mathcal P$. So the poset $(\mathcal P,\subseteq)$ fulfills the assumptions of Zorn Lemma.

By Zorn Lemma there exists a maximal $S'_g\in\mathcal P$. It only remains to show that $S'_g\cup S_i$ generates $V$. (We will use maximality of $S'_g$ in the proof.)

Answer (score 0):

Say $S_i = \{\vec v_1, \vec v_2, ... \vec v_n \}$.

Assume that there does not exist any vector $\vec v \in S_g$ such that $\{ \vec v \cup S_i \}$ is linearly independent.
  Now for every vector $\vec v \in S_g$ there exists $a, a_1, a_2, ...$ such that $ a\vec v + a_1 \vec v_1 + a_2 \vec v_2 + ... + a_n \vec v_n = \vec 0 $.
  However, by the linear independence of $S_i$,  $a \neq 0$.
  Now we have a expression of $\vec v$ in terms of $ \vec v_1, \vec v_2, ... \vec v_n $, and so we have shown $S_i$ itself generates $V$.

Else, there exists a $\vec v \in S_g$ such that $\{ \vec v \cup S_i \}$ is linearly independent. Then just add this $\vec v$ to $S_i$.

By repeating this procedure, we will end up with a linearly independent extension of $S_i$ that generates $V$, because $S_g$ generates $V$ so even in the worst case, we can add all of $S_g$ to $S_i$.

The vectors of $S_g$ we have added to $S_i$ forms the desired subset $S_g' \subseteq S_g$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider $S_1 = \{S_i \cup \{w\} |w \in S_g\}$. If $\nexists$ a subset of linearly independent vectors $S \subset S_1$, then $S_i$ is a maximal set of linearly independent vectors (and therefore a basis of $V$).

Indeed, given $v \in V$, since $v=\displaystyle{\sum _{w \in S_g} \lambda (w) w}$, $S_i \cup \{v\}$ is not linearly independent, because $S_i \cup \{w\}$ is linearly dependent for any $w \in S_g$.

If $\exists w \in S_g$ so that $S_i \cup \{w\}$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, we repeat the process with $S_i \cup \{w\}$ instead of $S_i$ and $S_g-\ \{w\}$ instead of $S_g$. This process will end, since $S_g$ and $S_i$ are or finite or countably infinite.

Finally, we get a set $S_i \cup \{w_1, w_2, ...\}$ which is a maximal set of linearly independent vectors, and therefore a basis of $V$. The desired set $S_g '$ is $\{w_1, w_2, ...\}$.

Answer (score 0):

This question, thanks to comments on https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160380/basis-of-a-vector-space-v, is based on Zorn lemma. The former answers are not correct if $V$ is nor finite nor countable. The fact is if $V\neq \lbrace\mathbf{o}\rbrace$  and if $S_i\subset V$ linearly independent and $\Gamma=S_i\cup S_g$ set of generators, there are a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ that
$$S_i\subset \mathcal{B}\subset\Gamma$$
A demonstration is on the book of S. Lang, \emph{Algebra}.